# Angular: Render null value in table cell

Tags: angular

How can I force my view to render null values into the template as a blank space?

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let key of keys">
    <!-- may evaluate to null but I want the row anyway -->
    <td>{{ foo[key]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null value is output as empty content, which collapses the cell. The same thing happens if the cell contains only space characters. To get a non-collapsed cell, you can insert an unbreakable space in it when the value is null:

```
<td>{{ foo[key] || "&nbsp;" }}</td>
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahw1fr).

Answer (score 0):

Straight-forward solution for this that I've used many times:

`<td>{{ (foo[key] || '') }}</td>`

Comment: I believe this renders nothing, not an empty `td`